# How to compute using the within same column

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse

Table 1 has account information let's say

AccountTable

```
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+
| Account_Name | Account_Number | Currency |   Date   |
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+
| Test 1       |           1234 | USD      | 20190228 |
| Test 2       |          5678  | JPY      | 20190228 |
| Test 3       |           9012 | AUS      | 20190228 |
| Test 4       |           3456 | MEX      | 20190228 |
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+
```

then table 2 have currency information

CurrencyTable

```
CurrencyName|CurrencyRate|Date
USD         |50.9999     |20190228
KRW         |1.52422     |20190228
JPY         |11.2232     |20190228
MEX         |6.2323      |20190228
AUS         |5.1111      |20190228
```

and so on...

I need an output like

```
Account_Name|Account_Number|CurrencyName|USCurrency|Date
Test1       |1234          |US          |1.0000    |20190228
Test2       |5678          |JPY         |572.3820  |20190228
Test3       |9012          |AUS         |260.6655  |20190228
Test4       |3456          |MEX         |317.8466  |20190228
```

on USCurrency column I need to multiply/compute the other currency to US rate. I have no problems on joining the two table. What I don't know is how to compute the rate within the same column. Thank you!!

Comment: Assuming the AccountTable really has a balance, then `AccountBalance*CurrencyRate as USCurrency` in the `SELECT`  result set with the right `JOIN`s is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Except that your output does not make much sense to me (more on that below), the trick is to use your `CurrencyTable` twice.

```
SELECT Account_Name, Account_Number, A.Currency, C2.CurrencyRate * C1.CurrencyRate AS USCurrency, A.Date
FROM AccountTable A
JOIN CurrencyTable C1 ON A.Date = C1.Date AND A.Currency=C1.CurrencyName
JOIN (SELECT * FROM CurrencyTable WHERE CurrencyName='USD') C2 ON A.Date = C2.Date
```

As you will notice in the result, `USCurrency` for row = `USD` does not return 1. It would have needed to **divide** the 2 rates by each other to get this result but for some reason, you are asking for a product in your desired output.

I believe what you want is `C2.CurrencyRate / C1.CurrencyRate AS USCurrency` or `C1.CurrencyRate / C2.CurrencyRate AS USCurrency`, which of course changes all the records.

Comment: i just need to find a way to compute the currency on currencyrate. For example USD multiplied by other currency (e.g. US * JPY, US * MEX, US * AUS) and output in USCurrency

Comment: This multiplication (e.g. `USD * JPY`) is **exactly** what I have done. I just said you may want to divide instead, as this results in multiplying USD by USD.

Comment: IMHO, that's a clear sign you wanted something different from what you asked, sorry if I am mistaken;

Answer (score 0):

First store the us currency in a variable and run the select query:

```
SET @US_CURRENCY := (SELECT CurrencyRate FROM CurrencyTable WHERE CurrencyName = 'USD');

SELECT AccountTable.Account_Name, 
AccountTable.Account_Number, 
CurrencyTable.CurrencyName,
IF( CurrencyTable.CurrencyName = 'USD', CurrencyTable.CurrencyRate/@US_CURRENCY, CurrencyTable.CurrencyRate*@US_CURRENCY ) AS USCurrency, 
AccountTable.Date
FROM AccountTable
LEFT JOIN CurrencyTable
ON AccountTable.Currency = CurrencyTable.CurrencyName;
```

Comment: actually this is my last resort. i'm trying to figure it out using only subquery or joins. thanks chayan

Answer (score 0):

You need CASE statement in your SQL to calculate USCurrency for non US Currency.
select
Account_Name, Account_Number,CurrencyName,
CASE When CurrencyName = 'JPY'
THEN CurrencyTable.CurrencyRate * (Select CurrencyRate from CurrencyTable where CurrencyName = 'US')
WHEN CurrencyName = 'MEX'
THEN CurrencyTable.CurrencyRate * (Select CurrencyRate from CurrencyTable where CurrencyName = 'US')
WHEN CurrencyName = 'AUS'
THEN CurrencyTable.CurrencyRate * (Select CurrencyRate from CurrencyTable where CurrencyName = 'US')
END USCurrency,
Date
FROM AccountTable A
JOIN CurrencyTable C1 ON A.Date = C1.Date 
AND A.Currency=C1.CurrencyName